# Why two Zubats with same CP has diferent CP bar?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the following screenshots I have two Zubat pokemons with same CP, can someone explain why the CP bar is not in the same position?

[image: CP 154, lower bar]
[image: CP 154, higher bar]

Comment: The stats for both are the same: 10 attack and 30 special. My trainer level is 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the IV for these two Pokemon are different.

[IV Calculator](https://thesilphroad.com/research)

> Perfect IV's means that a pokemon has the best possible stats for its species, and therefore, has the potential to reach the highest possible CP for its species. For example, a low IV pokemon might top out at 2700 CP at max level, but a pokemon with higher IVs could reach 3000+ CP at max level.

[Read more about IV here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/278111/125786)