# What affects IV's in Pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Well, it is known that beside base stats pokemon have their individual stats(IVs) and there are sites that help to calculate them for any pokemon. 
My question is How these IVs are determined by the game? I mean, is there anything that affects these stats while they're generated? Is this completely random? Or is there any way to catch better pokemons or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Pokemon GO, what are my Pokemon's hidden IV stats, and why do they matter?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276692/in-pokemon-go-what-are-my-pokemons-hidden-iv-stats-and-why-do-they-matter)

Comment: RNG's through and through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pokémon you catch in the wild have completely random IVs, with a bell curve applied so most pokémon you find are average, and finding particularly good or bad ones is rare.

Pokémon you hatch from eggs are more likely to have good IVs, with the average being somewhere around 80% perfect.

Sources: [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4v63xk/psa_egg_iv_distribution/), [2](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/egg-hatching-chart/)

Comment: So the way you throw a ball, the kind of ball, number of throws, accuracy, using berry etc doesn't affect IVs?

Comment: @MrCheatak Nope, the IVs are determined as soon as the pokemon appears in your game.

Comment: The fact IVs are determined the moment you see it can be deduced easily from the fact that you can see the pokemon's CP. Since CP is based on IVs the IVs must be known to be able to see a CP value.