# Should I prefer higher IV totals or higher max CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have 2 Grimers with the following stats:

- 89% (15/13/12) with a max possible CP of 2677
- 93% (13/15/14) with a max possible CP of 2676

I have read that the CP formula values Attack more than Defense or Stamina, this is why the lower percentage Grimer has an overall higher CP. Question is, should I also value Attack and therefore CP more? Which Grimer is better?

NOTE: I am not asking about CURRENT CP vs IVs like [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286325/), I am asking about MAXIMUM CP at level 40 versus IV%.

Comment: @Oak my question is not the same as that one. I am asking about MAX cp and not just cp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your use of the Pokemon.

For example, a Pokemon with a higher defense takes less damage, and a higher stamina means they lose less CP when defending a gym. A higher attack means they deal more damage, (obviously).

So it's up to you what you prefer more; an attacker or a defender, or you can simply keep both - one for attacking the gym, and the other for defending it once you take it down.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that in this case for Grimer (and Muk) in Pokemon Go their primary use would be defence of gyms or something like that, I don't think I've ever seen one used for attacking.

Comment: @Theyna Yes, some pokemons are better for defence as you mentioned Muk, or Snorlax, Chensey etc.